# Change permalink in wp-property

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks

I have set default property page so in the property url it shows /lima-investments/property-name. But I want to remove /lima-investments from the url.

I want to change following url

http://example.com/lima-investments/miraflores-apartment-for-rent-terrace/

to

http://example.com/miraflores-apartment-for-rent-terrace/

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this...
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Answer (score 0):

Change the permalink in the admin->settings->permalink

add

```
%postname%
```

in Custom permalink

Comment: I have already tried this. But doesn't work for me. Can you suggest anything more.

Comment: if you have created page or post for this then edit the link form the admin for related pade or post.

Answer (score 0):

This means that "miraflores-apartment-for-rent-terrace" is a sub page of "lima-investments", right?
Try to Remove the parent page of "miraflores-apartment-for-rent-terrace". Edit "miraflores-apartment-for-rent-terrace" page. Go to Page Attribute section. Change the Parent drop-down to (no parent)

Comment: I have used wp-property plugin. miraflores-apartment-for-rent-terrace is not a subpage. It is a property (which is custom post-type).